# Simple string.equals() if statement not working Java

Tags: java, string, equals

I'm about to go crazy. Maybe it's cause I've been working for 12 hours....but why will my if statment not evaluate to true when running `if (band.equals("4384")`?? I am printing `band` to the screen and it is reading `4384` but it will not evaluate to true. I've used .equals() so many times with out issue, what am I doing wrong?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String endBand = " ";

        String str = "SCELL: UARFCN 4384, Prim. SC: 362, RSCP: 70, EcNo: 44";

        endBand = getBandNumber(str);

        System.out.println("endBand is " + endBand);

    }

    // ************************************************
    // Returns the current band that the device is on.
    // Currently only coded for 3G
    // ************************************************
    private static String getBandNumber(String str) {

        // The string returned to str will be in the form of:
        // "SCELL: UARFCN  4384, Prim. SC: 362, RSCP: 73, EcNo: 33"
        // ^^^^
        // String str = read_AT("AT+XL1SET=\"IRATSCEL?\"", 10);

        String band = " ";
        int begin = 0, end = 0;

        // Filter through the string to extrace the channel number
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

            char c = str.charAt(i);

            if (c == 'N' && str.charAt(i + 1) == ' ') {

                begin = i + 1;

            } else if (c == ',') {

                end = i;

                break;

            }

        }

        band = str.substring(begin, end);
        System.out.println("band is " + band);

        if (band.equals("4384")) {

            band = "5";

        } else {

            band = "2";
        }

        return band;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a space in your band variable in front of 4384. Try to print like this:

```
System.out.println("band is '" + band + "'");
```

Comment: Note the single-quotes around the `band` variable to show you where it begins and ends--so you can see any unexpected whitespace. This is a useful pattern! (Also, use String formatting instead of contatenation; it's much cleaner: `String.format("band is '%s'", band)`)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize I was including the space.

Answer (score 7):

Upon evaluation, you are ending up with a String that is actaully eqaul to `" 4384"` (note the space).

Try using...

```
if (band.trim().equals("4384")) {...
```

Instead

Comment: I think I will use this actually from now on...so I won't over look the space.

Comment: Just make sure you are also checking that the `band` is not `null` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 // Filter through the string to extrace the channel number
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

        char c = str.charAt(i);

        if (c == 'N' && str.charAt(i + 1) == ' ') {

            begin = i + 2; //i + 2

        } else if (c == ',') {

            end = i;

            break;

        }

    }
```